# Can I know the number of parameters passed in stored procedure in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a stored procedure in a Oracle Database that receives 3 parameters.

I know that I call it with 1 to 3 parameters but it's possible to know inside itself how many arguments are the defaults or are really passed?

For example:

- dummy(1) some keyword say me "1"
- dummy(1,2,3) say me "3"

I ask this because I worked with Informix 4GL and I could use "NARGS" to know the number of arguments that I receive.

Comment: you mean, you want to know argument number inside SP?

Comment: Yes, that's the question. I need to know it to execute some pieces of code depending on the numbers of arguments. Thanks

Comment: Then set default value to null, and check if the parameters are null or not.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.. there is not an equivalent to NARGS or "C"s argc.

if you are using null default values you could manually count the number of arguments that do no equal the default value.. but that wont tell you if you explicitly pass the default value as a parameter.

i can think of 2 solutions.
1. user overloaded procedures .. ie

```
procedure a (p_1 number);
procedure a (p_1 number, p_2 number);
procedure a (p_1 number, p_2 number, p_3 number);
```

then in the bodies you would "know" by which one you are in.

option 2. pass a varray/plsql table as a single argument  but then actually passing the arguments becomes problematic.

```
create or replace package x
is

type an_arg is record ( n number, v varchar2(2000), d date);
type args is table of an_arg;

procedure a(argv args);

end;
/

create or replace package body x
is

procedure a(argv args)
is
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('i was passed '||argv.count||' arguments');

end;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ShoeLace's answer, I think counting the number of parameters that do not equal the default of each parameter would work.

The key to this is to give each parameter a nonsensical default value. Like '~#dummee_v@1u3#~' maybe. Anything you are confident will never actually be passed in. This way you don't have to worry about somebody passing in a parameter value that equals the default value.

So:

```
create procedure p1 (id1 varchar2 default '~#dummee_v@1u3#~', id2 varchar2 default '~#dummee_v@1u3#~') is
     lParamCount number := 0;
     lDummyParamValue varchar2 := '~#dummee_v@1u3#~';
     begin
          if id1 <> lDummyParamValue then lParamCount := lParamCount + 1;
          if id2 <> lDummyParamValue then lParamCount := lParamCount + 1;
     end p1;
```